# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. "28\08\2014"

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

I have this format in our database "26\08\2014" but when I try to use the Convert.ToDateTime and DateTime.Parse its not working but when I change the data from "26\08\2014" to "08\26\2014" using the Immediate Window, it works.

Current Code:
`string dateFromDB = @"26/08/2014"; //day/month/year
 DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateFromDB);`

Comment: You need to specify the format using `ParseExact`

Comment: I still got the error.  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(@"28\08\2014", @"MM\dd\yyyy", null));

Comment: The edit you've made to the question which includes your current code will work. The date strings in your initial question and your edit are different: `"26\08\2014"` vs. `"26/08/2014"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the format string to prevent them from being interpreted by the format engine:

```
@"MM\\dd\\yyyy"
```

Also, 28 is not a valid month.

Comment: It's a `day` actually... from datasource the format is "dd\mm\yyyy"

Comment: @Ian: Then your format string is wrong.  If you correct it and escape it, it will work.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, At first I thought that It will format what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"28\08\2014", @"dd\\MM\\yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("28\\08\\2014", @"dd\\MM\\yyyy", null)
```